# "Your request exceeded the time limit for processing." when editing any code

Tags: visualforce, apex, developer-console, platform-bug

I've been encountering this platform error when trying to update any code from the `App > Setup`:

> **Time limit exceeded**
>
> Your request exceeded the time limit for processing.

For example, if I go in `App > Setup > Develop > Pages` and click `Edit` next to a Visualforce page, it takes forever to open, or sometime end up hitting the error copied above.

This error is not displayed when I'm using the `Developer Console` or when syncing using for example Mavensmate or the Force.com IDE.

What is wrong?

Comment: What instance are you on?

Comment: Does this happen even in really small pages? How long has this been happening (potentially just a server burp)?

Comment: I wondered that too, but it's happening on every type / size. I noticed that degradation about 3 months ago, and it got worse over time. It"s weird because it's only happening through the App Setup menu, not the developer console.